# Java custom logger issues

Tags: java, logging

I have a custom `Logger` class:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Logger extends PrintStream{

    public Logger(OutputStream outputStream) {
        super(outputStream);
        logHeader();
    }

    private void logHeader(){
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) print("#");
        print("Program execution start: ");
        print(CalendarClock.getInitTimeStamp());
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) print("#");
        println();
    }

    public void logFooter(){
        for (int i=0; i<=20; i++) print("#");
        print("Program execution stop: ");
        print(CalendarClock.getCurrentTimeStamp());
        for (int i=0; i<=20; i++) print("#");
        println("\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String arg0) {
        super.print(arg0);
        if (this.out != System.out) System.out.print(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        if (this.out != System.out) System.out.println(arg0);
    }
}
```

And here is my `main` class:

```
public class Main {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File logFile = new File("data/test.log");
        Logger logger;

        try{
            if (!logFile.exists()) logFile.createNewFile();
            logger = new Logger(new FileOutputStream(logFile, false));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger = new Logger(System.out);

        }                                   
        logger.println("Hello World.");
        logger.println("Foo Bar");          
        logger.logFooter();
        logger.close();

    }

}
```

Firstly, Eclipse keeps displaying a warning at `logger = new Logger(System.out);` inside the `catch(IOException e)`: `Resource leak: 'logger' is not closed at this location`. I have to add `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` to make it disappear.

Secondly this program outputs the following to the console:

```
####################Program execution start: 2015-10-27 10:55:51####################Hello World.Hello World.
Foo BarFoo Bar
#####################Program execution stop: 2015-10-27 10:55:51#####################
```

while it logs to file correctly:

```
####################Program execution start: 2015-10-27 10:55:51####################
Hello World.
Foo Bar
#####################Program execution stop: 2015-10-27 10:55:51#####################
```

Lastly, if I run the following code:

```
public class Main {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File logFile = new File("data/test.log");
        Logger logger;

        try{
            throw new IOException("Threw the exception!");
            /*if (!logFile.exists()) logFile.createNewFile();
            logger = new Logger(new FileOutputStream(logFile, false));*/
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger = new Logger(System.out);
            logger.println(e.getMessage());
        }           
        logger.println("Hello World.");
        logger.println("Foo Bar");
        logger.logFooter();
        logger.close();

    }

}
```

the output is correctly printed as:

```
####################Program execution start: 2015-10-27 10:59:18####################
Threw the exception!
Hello World.
Foo Bar
#####################Program execution stop: 2015-10-27 10:59:18#####################
```

Obviously, this all seems to be beyond my understanding, and any explanation of this behavior would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I solved the issue of no new line at the end of the header by overriding the null argument `println`:

```
@Override
public void println() {
    super.println();
    if (out != System.out) System.out.println();
}
```

Now the output of the first `main` is:

```
####################Program execution start: 2015-10-27 11:15:30####################
Hello World.Hello World.
Foo BarFoo Bar
#####################Program execution stop: 2015-10-27 11:15:30#####################
```

Comment: first of all, you should not add @SuppressWarning, but you should wrap logger.close(); with "finally" clause. You should never forget to wrap close() methods with finally clause. This should be done to be sure that even if exception is thrown, connection will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a debugger to see the sequence of code execution, and found that the `PrintStream` class implements `prinln(arg0)` as a call to `print(arg0)` and `newline()` which is equivalent to `println()`. Thus every time `println(arg0)` was called in `Logger`, `arg0` was printed to `stdout` twice, once in `print(arg0)` and once in `println(arg0)`.

To overcome my problem, I changed the implementation of `println(arg0)` in `Logger` class to this:

```
@Override
public void println(String arg0) {
    print(arg0);
    println();
}
```